# Como aplicar scrollbar somente no elemento tbody em uma tabela HTML?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Como aplicar o `scrollbar` (barra de rolagem) somente no elemento `tbody`, assim deixando o elemento `caption` e `thead` fixo na tabela, sem se movimentar quando o `scrollbar` se move.

Abaixo segue o `HTML` e `CSS` da tabela:

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
.table caption {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
.table thead {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
}

.table tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
   <caption>Notas</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Avaliação 1:</th>
      <th>Avaliação 2:</th>
      <th>Trabalho:</th>
      <th>Avaliação Substitutiva:</th>
      <th>Nota Final:</th>
      <th>Falta(s):</th>
      <th>Situação:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Fiz https://jsfiddle.net/vqfmrj1x/1/, mas desconfio que não é bem o que quer... Ou é?

Comment: Não, o tbody teria que está abaixo do thead, e o caption está fixed também.

Comment: Dessa forma também já tentei.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mude o display do `thead` e do `tbody` para `block`, defina o tamanho máximo do elemento `tbody` e o modifique a propriedade `overflow-y` para `scroll`.

```
thead, tbody{
  display: block;  
}

tbody{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
  }
```

Foi necessário especificar o tamanho das colunas (`td` e `th`) para alinhar o conteúdo com o cabeçalho da tabela.

```
.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 5px;
  width:20%;
}
```

**Código completo**

```css
thead, tbody{
  display: block;  
}

tbody{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
  }

body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
.table caption {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 5px;
  width:20%;
}
.table thead {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
}

.table tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
   <caption>Notas</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Avaliação 1:</th>
      <th>Avaliação 2:</th>
      <th>Trabalho:</th>
      <th>Avaliação Substitutiva:</th>
      <th>Nota Final:</th>
      <th>Falta(s):</th>
      <th>Situação:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado, praticamente é o que quero, porém o thead fica desalinhado, em relação ao tbody.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esse problema eu apliquei a seguinte solução:

Primeiramente definir a `.table thead tr` como um elemento de bloco e em posição relativa:

```
.table thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

Definir um tamanho para o `.table td` e `.table th` com no minimo 15% de tamanho dentro da tabela, para não ficarem com tamanhos diferentes um em relação ao outro:

```
.table td,
.table th {
  min-width: 15%;
}
```

E como a colona 4 é um pouco maior, definir um tamanho de `150px`:

```
.table td:nth-child(4),
.table th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 150px;
}
```

E para finalizar, definir o `tbody` da seguinte forma, deixando ele como um elemento de bloco de altura de `300px` e largura de `100%` dentro da tabela, e para mostrar o scrollbar definir a propriedade `overflow` como `auto`, para mostrar tanto o scrollbar da esquerda quanto o de baixo do `tbody`:

```
.table tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Solução completa:

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
.table caption {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
.table thead {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
}
.table thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.table td,
.table th {
  min-width: 15%;
}
.table td:nth-child(4),
.table th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 150px;
}
.table tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.table tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
.table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #888;
}
.table tbody tr td:hover {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
   <caption>Notas</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Avaliação 1:</th>
      <th>Avaliação 2:</th>
      <th>Trabalho:</th>
      <th>Avaliação Substitutiva:</th>
      <th>Nota Final:</th>
      <th>Falta(s):</th>
      <th>Situação:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">-</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Aprovado</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```