# Existe alguma forma de colocar Scroll no TBODY?

Tags: html, css, table

Tenho uma tabela onde a quantidade de itens listados no `TBODY` é bem grande e eu gostaria de adicionar um scroll, definindo o tamanho máximo do `TBODY` em 500px.

Tentei fazer isso, porém não deu certo (Estou usando o Google Chrome)

```css
#scroll{
   max-height: 100px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="scroll">
     <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Porémm fazendo algo parecido com `DIV`, funciona perfeitamente:

```css
#scroll{
   max-height: 100px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
  <div>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
      <span>Valor</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Como posso fazer pra definir um `overflow` com scroll dentro de um `TBODY`?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134380/como-aplicar-scrollbar-somente-no-elemento-tbody-em-uma-tabela-html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar `overflow-y: auto` e `overflow-x: hidden`.

```css
thead, tbody { display: block; }

tbody {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Scroll vertical             */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Desativar scroll horizontal */
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th width="30px">A</th>
    <th width="30px">B</th>
    <th width="30px">C</th>
    <th width="30px">D</th>
    <th width="30px">E</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="scroll">
     <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
    </tr>
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Cara, a ideia é bacana, mas o `TH` ficaria desalinhado em relação ao `TD`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Por que ficaria? Tá desalinhado no snnipet porque não tem formatação nenhuma.

Comment: Eu fiquei pensando que poderia ser algo do Chrome, mas vi que na resposta linkada funciona perfeitamente :D